# Update errors from the component children to the parent in a ReactJS Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, validation

I'm trying to clean 2 fields in a form with the X button that is shown in the picture. When 1 of the 2 fields have a value an error is shown in the form (this is the normal behavior), I have 1 error shown if 1 of the two fields is blank (the condition is the two fields in blank or the two fields filled) but when I click on X button this error should be removed because the two fields could be blank, I have the problem that the error isn't hidden on click in the X button (this error should disappear).

You can see the two fields here:

[image: Two fields of the form]

It seems that the formValidation isn't checked fine because the form doesn't update the messages that should appear in the form.  (I'm realizing this actions on a component field file Field.jsx and the checking of the formValidation is in the main form create file Form.jsx). My button is declared this way:

```
<button
  id="button__value_input"
  name="button_reset"
  type="button"
  className={styles['button']}
  onClick={() => this.resetFields(slug)}
>
```

I think that I should send the error updating validation from the children component file(Field which is inside Form) to the parent component file (Form), but in which way can I send the error updating from children to the parent that should update and delete the error message (because on click in the X the error messages should disappear in the correct way of cleaning the two fields).

When I do changes in the input fields the formValidation errors are updated but with this reset button, that cleans the fields, the error updating is not reflected in the parent component field.

I have the import formValidation file in Field.jsx:

```
import validateForm from '../../Form/formValidation';
```

But I have the check of the validations in Form.jsx father component:

```
validate = (values) => {
    const errors = validate(values);
    //here are returned the errors:
    return Object.keys(errors).reduce(
      (prev, next) => ({ ...prev, [next]: this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: errors[next] }) }),
      {},
    );
```

};

If I do a `console.log` of the up errors line is appreciated when I update inputs but not appreciated in the `Field.jsx` field on the up button click.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Welcome. We might need you to show a bit more related code.